# Отсутствие прав доступа к файлу на localhost

Tags: apache, windows, github, yii

Периодически после скачивания ветки с github Yii выдаёт ошибку:

```
copy(Z:\home\localhost\www\insur\insurance\assets\c75d288a\css\_notes\dwsync.xml) [<a href='function.copy'>function.copy</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

dwsync.xml - это файл, автоматически создаваемый DW в процессе работы (нужен для заметок разработчика). Непонятно следующее:

1. Зачем Yii пытается выполнить

   **copy($path,$dst.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file); для этого файла ([site_root]\yii\framework\utils\CFileHelper.php(130))**
2. Как вообще может быть конфликт с правами доступа под Windows?
3. Где, собственно, источник проблемы - Windows, Apache или Yii?
4. Как решить?

Одним словом, для решения задачи нужен true Guru.
Верю, что такие есть! :)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю почти ничего о Yii, но открыл CFileHelper.php(line 130). JavaDoc по методу, в котором ошибка, гласит:

1. Copies a directory.
2. This method is mainly used by {[@link](/users/1693/link) copyDirectory}

Какие выводы делаю из этого я для себя: Вы, выполняете действия с директориями, при этом в одной из них взят конфигурационный файл Adobe DW. При этом, пытаетесь пользоваться Yii в тот момент, когда DW использует файл (Вы сами подчеркнули) в процессе работы. Конечно файл открыт внутри DW, так как он всегда готов туда что-либо записать, и конечно же php не получает прав для открытия файла для копирования. В чём вопрос то?

Comment: Говоря политкорректно - в том, что, как я уже написал (прочтите ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО начало вопроса) - это происходит ПЕРИОДИЧЕСКИ. Т.е., говоря инчае - это именно внештатная ситуация.

Comment: @srgg67, периодически, когда процесс блокирует доступ к файлу? Согласен.